# Using NodeJS as a server-side platform for processing tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, server-side

Bit of background: I am looking at using NodeJS on a project which involves scraping content and storing it in Mongo. This activity should be ran automatically, as per the schedule.

Other functions include taking the items in the database (Mongo), forming them in to a Wordpress post, which is then imported using the XML import function.

I was looking at using Express to "structure" this mini-application as I (/was) am intending the add more functions over time and don't want to end up in a jumble.

Now the question: **What are my options when it comes to writing a NodeJS application which doesn't require a HTTP server and works on scheduled and possibly terminal input over SSH?**

Comment: questions asking about the "best way" to do stuff are either *too broad* or *primarily opinion based*. Close-voted.

Comment: Aware of this, thank you for pointing it out. I have re-written the question slightly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think Node is the write tool for this job? I would argue that if you don't need high levels of concurrency, the added complexity of the asynchronous programming makes Node a wrong choice. Personally I'd write something like this in Ruby or Python. My $0.02.

Comment: What do you by 'doesn't require a HTTP server?' If you want to make HTTP requests you will need a HTTP server.

Comment: @BFree, point taken, thank you.

Comment: @Nikita, what I mean is that the application does not need to respond over HTTP. I can still make requests out, I just don't need to be activity listening for requests.

Comment: You don't need Expressjs. Just use the `HTTP` core module and `htmlparser2` module in order to parse the requested webpages. Then once you have the parsed data use `mongoose` to interface with Mongodb.

Comment: I've written something rather similar. I used `phantom.js` with node to insert json into mongo, and I had a separate site serving data from mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a web server as part of your application then you don't have to. A http server is needed to listen to requests only, where as you are making http requests.

Within your app.js you can just set up a scheduled function call using the setInterval function and put your magic in there.

```
var scheduleTimer = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('Working...'); //do your stuff
}, 60000);
```

You could set up several functions similar to above, one for scraping and one for updating the blog, and each can break it's work down into tasks which update the mongo data store.

So, one process can work through a scraping list on a schedule, and update mongo.

Another task can work through that information (in it's own time) and update your site as per a different schedule if there was anything found.

Suggest using 'forever' to make sure this whole thing keeps running.